# Python Memory Profiling

Tags: python, memory, profiling

Hi everyone [Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqqa0.jpg),
I need the best module or method for monitoring memory consumption of python algorithm.
I tried to use the following method:

```
mprof  run algorithm.py

mprof plot
```

The result is shown in the plot. Could you please explain it to me? Does it mean that the total memory usage is 53 Mb? It seems to me that it is too small value.

The algorithm is for frequent itemsets mining and as I know these types of algorithms is expensive on memory usage.
Could you please suggest me the best and accurate method for monitoring memory consumption of algorithm?

Comment: Please format your code and image properly. Regarding your question, it is most properly that your process used 53MB of memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear for your reply. I have also used $memit method. But it resulted in:
peak memory: 62.85 MiB

Which one is more accurate: 
%mprof 
or 
%memit
?
And do you think that by using one of them all child processes are included?